Is DataSpell super slow training models?
I am working on a project where I have to train a couple of models, from Random Forest Regressor to Hybrid CNN-LSTM models.
I was using DataSpell for this, also using the GPU of my laptop for the training processes but it was very very very slow.
After that I started working again with local Jupyter Notebooks using Anaconda and it is much faster than DataSpell, even without using GPU.
Has anyone experienced something similar?
Does anyone know of a solution to this problem with DataSpell?
